# Add property or modify cookie in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies

I have a cookie that is already set in the code already. I just want to add a flag `{httponly: true}` to it. I tried with `merge` method but I get error saying that merge can not be applied to string. Then I tried with this  `cookies[:riko_added_http_only] << '; HttpOnly'`, but I see in the browser cookies that the cookie is not httponly.

So the question is how to add/modify cookie property or flag(as `httponly` or `secure`) after some value is already assigned to it?

Here is some exampe:

```
    cookies[:riko_added_http_only] = {
      value: 'rikob',
    }
    ........ Some code here ....................
    cookies[:riko_added_http_only] << '; HttpOnly'
```

**EDIT**:

Let me add some more information and test examples:

From this code:

```
    cookies[:secure_true_http_true] = {
      value: 'httpOnly, not Secure',
      httponly: true,
      secure: true
    }
    cookies[:secure_true_http_false] = {
      value: 'Secure NOT HttpOnly',
      httponly: false,
      secure: true
    }
    cookies[:secure_false_http_true] = {
      value: 'Secure and http only',
      httponly: true,
      secure: false
    }

    cookies[:riko_added_http_only] = {
      value: 'rikob',
    }

    cookies[:riko_added_http_only] = {
      value: "#{cookies[:riko_added_http_only]}; HttpOnly"
    }
```

I get this result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can update the cookie value in this way:

```
cookies[:riko_added_http_only]= { 
  value: "#{cookies[:riko_added_http_only]} ; HttpOnly"
}
```

Comment: Barratin

Thanks for the response, but this doesnt work for me. Have you tested it?

Comment: My bad, i misunderstood the question.  I made some test with this code:
```
cookies[:riko_added_http_only]= { 
  value: cookies[:riko_added_http_only],
  httponly: true
}
```

but only if the cookie value change, the httponly flag is changed...